# Trying a Recyclerview inside another recyclerview in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

> Hello , I am trying to have a Recyclerview inside of the Recyclerview
>   with a fragment and I did not know how to return the another view
>   since the fragment needs only one view on return.

**My Fragment Class:**

```
    View inflatedView = null;
    View inflatedView1 = null;
    EppOrderHistoryItemsDetails items;
    EppOrderHistoryInsideItemsDetails insideItems;
    private List<EppOrderHistoryItemsDetails> dataItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<EppOrderHistoryInsideItemsDetails> dataInsideItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

**My Oncreate View:**

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_epp_order_history, container, false);
        inflatedView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_history_item_card_view, container, false);

        prepareItems();
        prepareInsideItems();


            insideItems(inflatedView1);
            Items(inflatedView);


            return inflatedView;
            //I'd like to return here (inflatedView1) here  too.


    }
```

**My Method Class:**

```
    private void Items(View inflatedView) {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.order_history_recyclerview_items);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        EppOrderHistoryItemsAdapter mAdapter = new EppOrderHistoryItemsAdapter(dataItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private void insideItems(View inflatedView1) {
        //InsideItems
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView1 = inflatedView1.findViewById(R.id.order_history_recyclerview_inside_items);
        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager1);
        EppOrderHistoryInsideItemsAdapter mAdapter1 = new EppOrderHistoryInsideItemsAdapter(dataInsideItems);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(mAdapter1);
    }

    private void prepareInsideItems() {
        insideItems = new EppOrderHistoryInsideItemsDetails("1", "asd", "1", "1234", "", "", "", "earphones?");
        dataInsideItems.add(insideItems);
        insideItems = new EppOrderHistoryInsideItemsDetails("2", "dfg", "2", "5678", "", "", "", "tv?");
        dataInsideItems.add(insideItems);
        insideItems = new EppOrderHistoryInsideItemsDetails("3", "qwe", "4", "913254", "", "", "", "speaker?");
        dataInsideItems.add(insideItems);
        insideItems = new EppOrderHistoryInsideItemsDetails("4", "efc", "5", "345", "", "", "", "phones?");
        dataInsideItems.add(insideItems);

    }


    private void prepareItems() {
        items = new EppOrderHistoryItemsDetails("1", "erg", "", "sdfg", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        dataItems.add(items);
        items = new EppOrderHistoryItemsDetails("2", "dfg", "", "sfdg", "", "", "", "ert", "", "", "");
        dataItems.add(items);
        items = new EppOrderHistoryItemsDetails("3", "sdfg", "", "sdfg", "", "", "", "sdgf", "", "", "");
        dataItems.add(items);
        items = new EppOrderHistoryItemsDetails("4", "sdfg", "", "sdfg", "", "", "", "sdfgdfs", "", "", "");
        dataItems.add(items);

    }


}
```

> Therefore I am looking too for other possibilities to do it.. not in
>   recyclerview only.

Heading

---

> this is my output if i call the return inflatedview:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVXyC.png)

> this is my output if i call the return inflatedview1:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGeCA.jpg)

Comment: Strange code. Why don't you put both recyclerViews inside a single layout and then inflate just that layout?

Comment: ive try that one sir, but the other recyclerview is not working.thus ive work also in fragment so that it has return view.

Comment: also the cove ive been posted was my second try, calling the view within the method but it is still not working. it is looking for the return view again for the fragment

Comment: You can only return a single view from fragment onCreateView method. Just add both recyclerViews in the first layout. Then move statements inside **inflatedview1** block into **Items(View inflatedView)** method block. Try to run and if it does not work. Rephrase your question on what you tried and post the result you got.

Comment: ow, sorry my code is not reliable. i found that i  could add a recycyclerview and add method on the adapter of the otherone. but in my code, i was trying to merge it in one fragment which is impossible...

Comment: by the way, thanks for response sir, ive appreciate your help :)